# Get numbers that have only 2,3 and 5 as prime factors

Tags: java

I am writing  a code to find numbers which have prime factor 2,3 or 5.Problem is that after testing the value which have prime factors 2,3 or 5, I am not able to put the value in an array array[j] without any space(i.e null value).Do you have any suggestion for this?I have marked the problem area.

```
 public class test{
 static int search(int i) 
 {
     for(int n=1;n<=Math.sqrt(i);n++){
     if(i==1){
     System.out.println(i);
     }
     else if(i%2==0){
     i=i/2;
     System.out.println(i);
     }
     else if (i%3==0){
     i=i/3;
     System.out.println(i);
     }
     else if (i%5==0){
     i=i/5;
     System.out.println(i);
     }
     }
     return i;
 }
public static void main(String[] args) {
int array[]= new int[100];
{
for(int i=1;i<100;i++)
{
 int m; 
 m=search(i);
 if(m==1||m==2 || m==3 || m==5){
  for(int j=i;j<=i;j++)
     array[j]=i;//Problem is here
  }
 }
 }
}
}
```

Comment: The array index is valid for 0..99 only. So start at 0, not at 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int array[]= new int[100];
{
int index=0;
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
 int m; 
 m=search(i);
 if(m==1||m==2 || m==3 || m==5){
 array[index++]=i;
}
}
}}
```

Have a look.i hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int array[]= new int[100];
{
int index=1;
for(int i=1;i<100;i++)
{
 int m; 
 m=search(i);
 if(m==1||m==2 || m==3 || m==5){
     array[++index]=i;
  }
 }
 }}
```

Try this please.